# Should I use dependency injection instead of class funcs?

Tags: ios, swift

I was reading a blog article by https://www.raywenderlich.com/ about the integration of health kit. For the communication with `HealthKitStore`, they used a class with a `class func` in it like this f.e.

```
class HealthKitSetupAssistant {
    class func authorizeHealthKit(completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Swift.Void) {
        // authorizing code
        // HKHealthStore().requestAuthorization(){}
    }
}
```

Now in the `ViewController` there they use it, they just call

```
HealthKitSetupAssistant.authorizeHealthKit { // completion handling }
```

I am wondering if this is the best way to do it. After all their communication with `HealthKitStore` was called over `class funcs`. I read in many blogs that I should use `dependency injection` instead of `static functions`. Is the opinion about `class funcs` different? So with `Dependency injection` I would create an instance of my `HealthKitSetupAssistant` class and pass the instance to the class/function I need to use it.

I am not sure if I should follow examples like these and use `class funcs` (as it feels more clear and easy) or if I should still use `dependency injection`.

Also, they create a new instance of `HealthKitStore` every time they use it. Wouldn't it be better to just create an instance once and use that instance everywhere I need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to you - for the purpose of a tutorial, it's likely that the author wanted to make the example as simple as possible for the reader to focus on the content at hand, in the same way many tutorials put networking code in view controllers. It's not recommended, but done to make the code as simple for the reader as possible

In general, the choice between static functions and dependency injection depends on what you want the function to do. Static functions work well when the process will never change and isn't influenced be external factors, and has the convenience of being called from anywhere. It also tells the user that the process isn't influenced by external factors (or at least it shouldn't be) which can be useful to know.

A static function works well here because this function will do the exact same thing every time (in this case, validate permissions, request permissions from the user, handle the response, etc), and has the convenience of being able to be called from anywhere in the application.

That said, dependency injection can provide more flexibility as it reduces dependencies between classes and can allow for more varied behaviour.

To take this case as an example, let's say you're developing your view controller, and you're testing your states. In your view controller you have a function like this:

```
HealthKitSetupAssistant.authorizeHealthKit { authorized, error in
    if authorized {
        self.showAccessGrantedDialog()
    } else {
        self.showAccessDeniedDialog()
    } else if let responseError = error {
        self.showErrorMessage(error)
    }
}
```

When testing how your UI responds, it can be quite tedious to constantly have to reset and re-grant permissions to see how your application handles the different cases, and can also be quite time consuming.

With dependency injection, instead you could create a protocol called HealthKitSetupAssistant that looks like this:

```
protocol HealthKitSetupAssistant {
   func authorizeHealthKit(completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void)
}
```

then create various instances for different behaviour. You could have an AccessGrantedAssistant, that looks like this:

```
class AccessGrantedAssistant: HealthKitSetupAssistant {
    func authorizeHealthKit(completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) {
        //instantly authorizes
        completion(true)
    }
}
```

then create different cases for AccessDeniedAssistant, and an ErrorOccurredAssistant, which would allow you to instantly check how your UI reacts to each case without having to go through the entire setup process over and over again.

This would also allow you to automate UI tests, giving you a guarantee that your view code can correctly handle each case.

Class functions aren't necessarily 'good' or 'bad', they're simply another tool, and you shouldn't always use dependency injection over them. It always depends on what the intention of the function is. For a tutorial / example, it works fine. But as complexity grows, dependency injection may be preferred.